# ERROR: Debug has an indirect dependency on Android API level 15, but minSdkVersion for variant 'debug' is API level 10

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin

I have a  maven based library project named LibA, the pom file just like below:

```
<groupId>com.google.apple</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

At the same time, I have a App project base on LibA, and use gradle build script to build the App. Below is build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "delete.larry.com.tobedelete"
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.apple:parent:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

When I run 'gradle build' to build the app, I get the errror:

```
 ERROR: Debug has an indirect dependency on Android API level 15, but minSdkVersion for variant 'debug' is API level 10
```

I know if I upgrade my minSdkVersion from 10 to 15, it will be OK.But I want to build the app from level 10. The library project use same api from 
level 15 but I write some code to fit lower api levle. So how could I declare in my pom.xml just like build.gradle's minSdkVersion attribute?

Comment: what the hell is com.google.apple ?-)

Comment: My library‘s groupId :)

Comment: then I would change this - e.g with this groupid you will never get your lib on maven-central

Comment: The question is not groupId. I just install at local, and never deploy. This library just a test library project

Comment: That's why this was not an answer, but a friendly comment. I think your question cannot be answered without you giving more details. Your data does not contain the problem.

Comment: Thank u for you comment. I don't what detail should provided; My question in a word is how maven to config the minSdkVersion for android library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I resolved this issue. I maked a stupid mistake,

This is the wrong depency:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is the right:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The default scope is compile and will package the 4.1.1.4 to app project as targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion, I assumed.